# Bundle install loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm running ruby 1.8.7 with rails 2.3.14... with bundler.

I've created a new application with:

```
rails new_app
cd new_app
```

Run the command:

```
bundle install
```

the terminal loops here:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
```

anything happen. What's going on?
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it printing this line over and over? how many times?

Comment: Sorry, I solved! Was trying to install gem "rspec-rails" through the Gemfile... but it's not compatible with rails2... instead I follow this guide https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/rails